# R - R6 - higher order function - scope of enclosing function

Tags: r, r6

I try to create dynamically the initialize function of R6 class.
First I create unlocked class definition:

```
   cls <- R6::R6Class(
       name,
       inherit=TPayload,
       lock_objects=FALSE,
       public=list(
           module=class(tail(Parser$thrift_stack, 1)[[1]])[[1]],
           ttype=ttype
       ))
```

And somewhere after I add an initialize function:

```
cls$set("public", 'initialize', init_func_generator(cls, default_spec))
```

where init_func_generator:

```
init_func_generator = function(cls, spec) {    
  func = function(...) {
    cat('Hello\n')
  }

  return(func)
}
```

Executing simple initialize function works when I create an object.

```
cli$new(name='abc')
```

However when I try to access 'spec' variable from outside scope of created 'initialize':

```
init_func_generator = function(cls, spec) {    
  func = function(...) {
    for(s in spec) {
      cat(str(s))
    }
  }

  return(func)
}
```

I get:

```
* object 'spec' not found
```

Is it possible what I try to achieve?

Comment: just to understand your needs a bit more, why can't you pass in `cls` and `spec` into the inner `func` (.e.g `func = function(cls, spec)`)?

Comment: you might need to add `force(cls); force(spec)` before your defintion of `func`. Or you can change the args to your `init_func_generator` to `...`

Comment: First, I create a R6 class definition basing on specification (thrift). I want that someone who creates an object can pass in constructor some values that will set the fields. 'spec' contains default values of those fields.
In constructor initialize, I want to set fields values either given in arguments or default that were in spec.

I want to achieve similar mechanism as is here https://github.com/eleme/thriftpy/blob/v0.3.9/thriftpy/thrift.py

Comment: force didn't help; in fact I am using 'spec' without problems in init_func_generator:
 
 
init_func_generator = function(cls, spec) {
  if(length(spec) == 0) return(function() { })
...
before definition of inner function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my solution to this:

```
init_func_generator = function(cls, spec) {
  if(length(spec) == 0) return(function() { })

  args <- alist()
  for(s in spec) {
    args[[s[[1]]]] <- s[[2]]
  }

  func <- function() {
    argg <- as.list(environment())
    for(arg_name in names(argg)) {
      self[[arg_name]] <- argg[[arg_name]]
    }
  }
  formals(func) <- args

  return(func)
}
```

So now I can do:

```
  print(s$Set$new(a_set=1)$a_set)
  [1] 1

  print(s$Set$new()$a_set)
  [1] NA
```

when the spec in this case is [('a_set', NA)]